Azure VM Scale Set for DevOps agent `dotnet restore` fails
I have created an Azure VM Scale Set from Windows Server 2022 Datacenter (SKU: 2022-datacenter-azure-edition). I created the necessary Agent Pool in my DevOps. I also created a Pipeline by importing my JSON from an existing one that runs fine on Azure Hosted pipeline for a while.
The project is a ASP.NET Core web app that has an angular frontend, thus needing Angular CLI and .NET Core SDK to build.
The issue is that several steps fail for apparently missing components. For example, when I run the standard ".NET Core Restore" step (task version 2.*) with its default settings as added in the UI or as I had it running in the hosted agent, it fails saying Packages failed to restore. Here is a longer piece of the debug logs:
##[debug]exec tool: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
##[debug]arguments:
##[debug]   restore
##[debug]   C:\a\1\s\src\PSTGI.Web.Host\PSTGI.Web.Host.csproj
##[debug]   --configfile
##[debug]   C:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_4143.config
##[debug]   --verbosity
##[debug]   Detailed
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" restore C:\a\1\s\src\PSTGI.Web.Host\PSTGI.Web.Host.csproj --configfile C:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_4143.config --verbosity Detailed
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application 'restore' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found

##[debug]Exit code 2147516561 received from tool 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
##[debug]rm -rf C:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_4143.config
##[debug]removing file C:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_4143.config
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 2147516561
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;source=TaskInternal;correlationId=72a52c2b-ae54-4390-aebe-09af966fac5a;]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 2147516561
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Packages failed to restore

Even more, I have also set in "Demands" npm and when I run a CMD task npm install --location=global @angular/cli, it also fails with
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
##[debug]Entering Invoke-VstsTool.
##[debug] Arguments: '/D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\a\_temp\858c1907-84ca-453d-9c29-1183939d9762.cmd""'
##[debug] FileName: 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe'
##[debug] WorkingDirectory: 'C:\a\1\s'
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\a\_temp\858c1907-84ca-453d-9c29-1183939d9762.cmd""
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
##[debug]Exit code: 1
##[debug]Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue correlationId=1bb0b42d-0b31-4061-9a43-5af26f0d6667;source=TaskInternal;type=error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]Error detected
##[debug]Leaving C:\a\_tasks\CmdLine_d9bafed4-0b18-4f58-968d-86655b4d2ce9\2.246.1\cmdline.ps1.

What I tried
Some suggested adding NuGetAuthenticate@1 and NuGetToolInstaller@1 tasks before the restore but it did not help.
I tried to check if .NET Core SDK is there, so I created a CMD step running dotnet --list-sdks, which does not log any output info but does not fail, making me think the Windows Server 2022 image or the Agent installs the latest SDK.
I also added a task UseDotNet@2 with no parameters hoping it will download the latest SDK, but the step is very quick (1-2 sec) and does not solve my problem.
The last thing I tried was to use the DevOps template for a ASP.NET Core pipeline with the same result - failing dotnet restore.
Questions
Why would these steps fail and how to make sure I have the .NET Core SDK?
Same about npm.

Have you tried using both the UseDotNet@2 and NuGetToolInstaller@1 tasks before trying to restore the packages? NuGetAuthenticate@1 might be needed as well, in case you're using a custom feed that requires authentication.

As I mentioned above, I tried both and it did not solve the problem.

Sorry I read that but I wasn't sure if you tried using all this tasks at the same time or if you tried one and then another task.

What do you mean "but the step is very quick" when using UseDotNet@2 task? It might be helpful if you could edit your question and show us the pipeline logs when running all these tasks: UseDotNet@2, NuGetToolInstaller@1and NuGetAuthenticate@1.

By "very quick" I meant 1-2 seconds. It appeared to me it did not do anything but check if dotnet was there and authenticated immediately with no errors.

That might happen if the tool is already in the cache. But as I mentioned, the logs of these tasks might be helpful.

Thank you, everyone! I am abandoning this approach for Docker containers. It takes too much time to debug.
